# Restrict Java Generic to a Class

Tags: java, generics

In C#, this is possible:

```
public interface IMyCoolInterface<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
}
```

So the generic is confined / restricted to a class.

Is this possible with Java?

Comment: unlike `C#` generics are always classes... so simply `IMyCoolInterface<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic parameters are always classes in Java. There's no other option. The language doesn't allow primitives to be parameters, and there's no equivalent to C#'s `struct`.

Comment: So no way to distinguish between "only accept classes" vs "only accept interfaces" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict it even further if you want the interface to be of a certain base type by adding the extends keyword within your generic

```
public interface MyGenericInterface<T extends List<?>> {

  T convert(String value);

}
```

Now every class that implements `MyGenericInterface` must use an object that extends List in its implementation

```
public class MyClass implements MyGenericInterface<ArrayList<String>> {

  @Override
  public ArrayList<String> convert(String value) {
    return new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```